# Can you have a member reference to a member std::shared_ptr<variable> within the same object?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm creating a C++ class, A, that has an object member variable, B, that should not be instantiated by default. I prefer not to use pointer syntax, because class B relies a lot in operator() and the code gets so messy.

In order to use reference as a member variable, but every time I want to access the object via the reference I end up with a segmentation fault.

Is it possible to make this work?

```cpp
class SomeClass {
    public:
        SomeClass(int argToInitSomeOtherClass);
    void someOtherFunction();

    private:
        std::shared_ptr < SomeOtherClass > MemberObject;
    SomeOtherClass & MemberObjectReference = * MemberObject;
};

class SomeOtherClass {
    public:
        SomeOtherClass(int initArg) {
            this - > member = initArg;
        };
    void whatever() {}; // I do nothing

    private:
        int member;
};

SomeClass::SomeClass(int argToInitSomeOtherClass) {
    MemberObject = std::make_shared < SomeOtherClass > (argToInitSomeOtherClass)
}

void SomeClass::someOtherFunction() {
    MemberObjectReference.whatever(); // Segmentation fault
}
```

If is there a way to hold a member object and instantiate it without default values in a non-static manner also solves my problem, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: There are a couple of misconceptions here about pointers and references. The first thing you should do is read up on how they work. For example, having a reference to a pointer is pointless (hehe). Just have the shared_ptr (or unique_ptr) and use it directly and skip the reference altogether

Comment: Once, you assign a (new) pointer to `MemberObject`, your `MemberObjectReference` becomes dangling. Even at construction, it references a "`nullptr` contents". The `MemberObject = std::make_shared<SomeOtherClass>(argToInitSomeOtherClass)` in constructor comes too late.

Comment: Still too late. Please, have a look how to construct (initialize) members.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the explanation, but I have tried doing the following: ```MemberObject = std::make_shared<SomeOtherClass>(argToInitSomeOtherClass); MemberReference = *MemberObject;``` and also gives segmentation fault.

Comment: If you want to store a value -> just store the value. If you want to store a shared pointer to object, just pass a shared pointer to object. Converting a raw pointer (or reference) to a shared pointer is wrong. A shared pointer should be initialized with a `new` (or even better with `make_shared`) or another shared pointer or a weak pointer. An address of a value is wrong. How should the shared pointer manage the life-time of something which might be allocated on stack (with life-time manage by scope).

Comment: Please, have in mind that I'm initializing the reference with a dereferenced pointer. AFAIK, a dereference object pointer should work the same as a member object: ```MemberObject->whatever()``` ==```(*MemberObject).whatever()```. Therefore I can't understand why I can't have a non pointer reference to this memory position, the internal counter of the shared_ptr should be just incremented by 1.

Comment: You already have easy access to lvalue `SomeOtherClass&`s, viz `*MemberObject`

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between member **assignment** in constructor vs. member **initialization** in constructor? May be, my answer makes this clear.

Comment: if you have an member that is optional you should take a look at `std::optional`

Comment: @Scheff I know they both existed but doesn't knew it could make such a difference, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what OP actually intends to achieve.

I would look for another design because the approach of OP seems to me fragile and prone to break with the least change of source code.

However, the actual mistake of OP is IMHO the wrong initialization in constructor:

The reference must be taken after initialization of shared pointer. Additionally, I make the shared pointer `const` to understrike that this will break (reference would become dangling) as soon as the shared pointer would be re-assigned. (The `const` makes such attempt a compiler error.)

Taking the reference of a pointee (regardless of whether pointed by a raw or a smart pointer) should be done carefully with life-time of pointee in mind. The reference in C++ doesn't do this itself – it's the responsibility of the author.

The fixed example of OP:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct SomeOtherClass {
  int member;
  explicit SomeOtherClass(int initArg = 0): member(initArg) { }
  void whatever() { std::cout << "SomeOtherClass::member: " << member << '\n'; }
};

class SomeClass {
  public:
    explicit SomeClass(int argForOther);
    SomeClass(const SomeClass&) = delete;
    SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass&) = delete;
    void someOtherFunction();
  private:
    const std::shared_ptr<SomeOtherClass> MemberObject;
    SomeOtherClass &MemberObjectReference;
};

SomeClass::SomeClass(int argForOther):
  MemberObject(std::make_shared<SomeOtherClass>(argForOther)),
  MemberObjectReference(*MemberObject)
{ }

void SomeClass::someOtherFunction()
{
    MemberObjectReference.whatever(); // Segmentation fault fixed
}

int main()
{
  SomeClass someClass(123);
  someClass.someOtherFunction();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
SomeOtherClass::member: 123
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab5f043b2a01616f)</kbd>

Comment: It's almost certainly a good idea here to also delete `SomeClass::operator=`.

Comment: @aschepler I felt somehow that I forgot something essential... ;-)